# Java adding third party source library to a project in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I want to use a third party source package in my project. I am using NetBeans IDE. I can add the binary jar file and I can compile my application. However, I sometimes need to change and customize the third party's code.

I tried to add the third party's source jar,

```
    MyProject> Customize > Libraries > Add Jar
```

but necessary libraries can not be found so the application can not be run or compiled.

I also tried to add the source code as a project, but it did not work either.

For resolve this issue, I can change the source code, create a new jar and then add the jar in my application's library. However, considering that I would need to test and may need to change the code many times, it is not a scalable solution.

Finally, I need a way to import third party source code in such a way that when I compile and build my application all changes (including the ones I do in the third party's code) take effect.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new project out of your third party source, and add it to buildpath, and only when you build/export/pack your project make sure it has the last version of jar

Comment: For all who are confused like me, I created new Java Project (From Existing Source) and show the third party's source code as source. Then click finish,2. then go to my own project and do configure-> Libraries->Add Project, and add the project that I created from existing third party source code. It worked. Thanks